# Using regex to turn a string into JSON

Tags: php, json, regex

I have a string like this :

```
{
"XXX"       "XXX"
"XXX"       "XXX"
"XXX"
{
    "XXX"       "XXX"
    "XXX"       "XXX"
    "XXX"
    {
        "XXX"       "XXX"
    }
    "XXX"
    {
        "XXX"       "XXX"
        "XXX"       "XXX"
        "XXX"       "XXX"
        "XXX"       "XXX"
        "XXX"       "XXX"
        "XXX"       "XXX"
        "XXX"       "XXX"
    }
    "XXX"       "XXX"
}
"XXX"
{
    "XXX"       "XXX"
    "XXX"
    {
        "XXX"       "XXX"
    }
    "XXX"
    {
        "XXX"       "XXX"
        "XXX"       "XXX"
        "XXX"       "XXX"
        "XXX"       "XXX"
        "XXX"       "XXX"
        "XXX"       "XXX"
        "XXX"       "XXX"
    }
    "XXX"       "XXX"
}
"XXX"
{
    "XXX"       "XXX"
    "XXX"
    {
        "XXX"       "XXX"
    }
    "XXX"
    {
        "XXX"       "XXX"
        "XXX"       "XXX"
        "XXX"       "XXX"
        "XXX"       "XXX"
        "XXX"       "XXX"
        "XXX"       "XXX"
    }
    "XXX"       "XXX"
}
"XXX"
{
    "XXX"       "XXX"
    "XXX"
    {
        "XXX"       "XXX"
        "XXX"       "XXX"
        "XXX"       "XXX"
        "XXX"       "XXX"
        "XXX"       "XXX"
    }
    "XXX"       "XXX"
}
"XXX"
{
    "XXX"
    {
        "XXX"       "XXX"
    }
    "XXX"
    {
        "XXX"       "XXX"
        "XXX"       ""
    }
    "XXX"
    {
        "XXX"       "XXX"
        "XXX"       ""
    }
    "XXX"
    {
        "XXX"       "XXX"
        "XXX"       ""
    }
    "XXX"
    {
        "XXX"       "XXX"
        "XXX"       ""
    }
    "XXX"
    {
        "XXX"       "XXX"
        "XXX"       ""
    }
    "XXX"
    {
        "XXX"       "XXX"
        "XXX"       ""
    }
  }
}
```

It looks like JSON, but it isn't : it's lacking all the commas (',') and all the colons (":"). I'm trying to find a way to parse it and turn into a valid JSON string.

My guess is to use the tabulations and the line breaks to find my way in the string, but so far I wasn't able to convert it to valid JSON.

I came up with this, which works but I believe is not very efficient or fail safe :

```
$e = explode( "\n", $string );
foreach( $e as $k => $l ) {

$next = str_replace( "\t", '', $e[ $k + 1 ] );
$isParam = strstr( $l, "\"\t\t\"" );
$currentClean = str_replace( "\t", '', $l );

if ( $isParam )
    $e[ $k ] = str_replace( "\"\t\t\"", '":"', $l );

if ( $isParam && $next != '}' )
    $e[ $k ] .= ',';

if ( $currentClean == '}' && $next != '}' && $next )
    $e[ $k ] .= ',';

if ( preg_match( '#^"(.*)"$#', $currentClean ) && !$isParam )
    $e[ $k ] .= ':';

}
$json = implode("\n", $e);
```

How to improve this ?

Comment: where does the string come from?

Comment: @AlexAndrei it comes from a service on which I have no control unfortunately.

Comment: You should ask the provider to fix this garbage into a valid format. If you start parsing the stuff, it will get worse and the provider will never get used to valid formats. Especially if you pay for the service.

Comment: Seems like your "json" example is corrupt. 24 `{` and only 23 `}` brackets.

Comment: I just came back and found the question ON HOLD so can't post an answer.
I observed that this problem would be easier to solve if I processed the lines of text in REVERSE ORDER.

My solution made use of four regular expressions:

'\}', 
'(\".*?\")\s+(\".*\")', 
'^\s*(\".*?\")(\s*)$', 
'^\{'

Comment: Thank you Michael. The question is on hold indeed, I've re-written it a little. I don't really know why it was considered "off-topic" though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you have several replaces at hand...so my answer comes with several calls (i try with all the text, it doesn´t need to be separated each line, just enter the full text).

```
//For the ":" before "}" and keys
$alltext = preg_replace("/(\"\w+\")\s+(\{|(\"\w*\"))/", "$1:$2", $alltext);

//For "," at the ends of the values:keys
$alltext = preg_replace("/(\"\w*\":\"\w*\")(?!\s+(\}|\{))/", "$1$2,", $alltext);

//For the "," at the end of each "}" that has a value after
$alltext = preg_replace("/(\})(\s+\")/", "$1,$2", $alltext);
```

PD: Dont know what your values are so thats why I left the \w+ in the answer. Let me know if it was helpful.

PD2:You can try it at [phpliveregex](http://www.phpliveregex.com/)

Comment: Works as expected, except it doesn't add the ":" in the case where we have "key":"value". Your code returns "key","value". Result at : http://pastebin.com/fgiiNV4v

Comment: fixed, i forgot completly the keys. Is more fast than your inital option?

Comment: It is most likely faster. At least, it's much more elegant ... ! Still I have an issue, at line 108. Trying to find out what it is. Result : http://pastebin.com/t718tcrK

Comment: I notice now, there is a "}" missing in the initial input, there are  24 { and only 23 } as @maxhb comment

Comment: Indeed. I think it's when I pasted in Stackoverflow's editor or something. Thank you. It works great :)

Answer (score 1):

Not completely perfect but a really good start:

```
// Replace '"xxx" "xxx"' by '"xxx": "xxx",'
$string = preg_replace('/("[^"]+")\s+("[^"]*")/','$1: $2,',$string);

// Replace '} "xxx" {' with "} "xxx": {", accept "}" and "{" for start/end
$string = preg_replace('/([{}])(\s+)("[^"]+")\s+([{}])/','$1$2$3:$4',$string);

// Replace ", {" by " {"
$string = preg_replace('/,(\s*[}{])/','$1',$string);

echo $string;
```

Problem: There is a `,` placed after each match by first regex. Should not be the case for the last value in a list of values as here:

```
...
"XXX":{
   "XXX": "XXX",
   "XXX": "", <-- Wrong!
}
...
```

Working code example can be found at http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/36f618bbeaaa861a88b873144e25232c5ba2c8e1

Comment: Good start indeed. It gets everything as it should except for that comma. I'll try to see if I can improve on your code. Thanks !

Comment: Added a third regex which will handle the `,` ;-)

Comment: Oups, something I didn't notice at first : it will not add a comma after this kind of case : "key":{"key":"value"},"key":.... (the comma after the "}").